# Use of uninitialized value of type Any in numeric context raku

Tags: raku

I've come across a programming question at [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/learnprogramming/comments/e7ggyf/got_denied_from_internship_this_was_one_of) (Take a look at the link for the question)

This was one the solutions in Python:

```
s="112213"
k=2
result=0
for i in range(len(s)):
    num_seen = 0
    window = {}
    for ind in range(i, len(s)):
        if not s[ind] in window:
            num_seen += 1  
            window[s[ind]] = 1
        else: 
            window[s[ind]] += 1 
        if   window[s[ind]] == k:
            num_seen -= 1
            if num_seen == 0:
                result +=1
        elif window[s[ind]] > k:
            break
print(result)
```

I've tried to port this solution into Raku and here is my code:

```
my @s=<1 1 2 2 1 3>;
my $k=2;
my $res=0;
for ^@s {
    my $seen = 0;
    my %window;
    for @s[$_..*] {
    if $^a == %window.keys.none {
        $seen++;
        %window{$^a} = 1;}
    else {  
        %window{$^a} += 1;}
    if %window{$^a} == $k {
        $seen--;
        if $seen == 0 {
        $res++;} }
    elsif %window{$^a} > $k {
        last;}}}
say $res;
```

It gives this error:

`Use of an uninitialized value of type Any in a numeric context in a block at ... line 13`

How to fix it?

Comment: It would be better if you used explicit variables for the loops. You're using $^a all over the places, and it's not clear whether what you mean is the internal or the external $^a.

Comment: I see out of bounds indexing, invalid use of placeholder variables, use of array indexing of a hash, and misleading indents...

Comment: @jjmerelo I've used the `$^a` to donate the *loop variable* of the second `for` loop. Yes it looks a bit way too many, but I couldn't think of any other alternatives. Are there any?

Comment: @raiph I couldn't check the out of bounds indexing and do the other corrections because the code as seen above, isn't working :)

Comment: I know the point of the challenge was to keep the complexity down BUT … https://tio.run/##Tc7LCsIwEIXhfZ7iELrtQKO4CRHxNcRCtBeCqZUkCkX67DG9gbMb/m9gXrWzhxi7AafKtCZ4KF4UQuz2nO59d5MspewBBSHBWNM7lJvMj8h80C7gy4AprStRiX9UP6uZpPF6AF9ZPheOpQCm2a4uiyCawJXOuqWPtu/ak7YWSqWPZLoa2RjjDw is an extremely idiomatic solution in less than 10 LOC.

Comment: This is idiomatic and reduces complexity in the same way: https://tio.run/##bZDBasMwEETv/oohuGA3lqgd6MUklP5GaYqSyI6wLAdJLg2l3@5uZBlaCOiwaN7Ozu5FWv08TW484CJtI4@eUe28VaZ1WToXBdIux3cC9Fe8nFSrvMMWUeXHoT/UCamt8GdpcRrQDBb7hWS7GyqsJwuigkvaKCM0mfTKZBHkUsveFQu8pql4RPmU13ObkV8eo9HSOWTRgEU6xw4o68DNEmNQzR3ugWyjoRedXKZxvkf6Eb5xa4yZ3v7J7/xVtPxT6FE6LjTlpyt0sQlh6z/hC0ofluCcx1CE/iQJPSeu9w6@KstqU21WRZXX0/QL

Comment: @user0721090601 Both of the solutions are very good because, as you stated they are both idiomatic and reduce the complexity. Actually I aimed for that sort of solution at the start but found myself merely translating a Python code  and then failing badly :(

Comment: @LarsMalmsteen I agree with JJ that it looks like your *main* mistake was using implicits (`$_` and placeholders like `$^foo`) too much and even incorrectly. Does it make sense to you that `$_ = 1; given 2 { print $^foo; if 3 { print $^foo }; print $^foo; print $_ }` displays `2321`? Maybe temporarily switch to always using explicit variables (`-> ...`) instead of `$_` and placeholder variables to eliminate errors related to implicits. That may well significantly improve your success rate and accelerate your learning of the rest of Raku.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't feel that's a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). There are too many issues with it for me to get in to. What I did instead is start from the original Python and translated that. I'll add some comments:

```
my \s="112213" .comb;      # .comb to simulate Python string[n] indexing.
my \k=2;
my $result=0;              # result is mutated so give it a sigil
for ^s -> \i {             # don't use $^foo vars with for loops 
    my $num_seen = 0;
    my \window = {}
    for i..s-1 -> \ind { 
        if s[ind] == window.keys.none {   # usefully indent code! 
            $num_seen += 1;  
            window{s[ind]} = 1
        } else {
            window{s[ind]} += 1
        }
        if window{s[ind]} == k {
            $num_seen -= 1;
            if $num_seen == 0 {
                $result +=1
            }
        } elsif window{s[ind]} > k {
            last
        }
    }
}
print($result)
```

displays `4`.

I'm not saying that's a good solution in Raku. It's just a relatively mechanical translation. Hopefully it's helpful.

Comment: 4 is the correct result because the Python solution gives 4, too. I didn't know that the unchanged variables could be donated without the `$` , `@` or `%`  prefix.

Comment: The `4` may be luck. I haven't tested it against other strings. And JJ's answer -- which stayed true to your code as best could be managed -- also computes `4` but reproduces what seems to be a bug in your Raku translation of the Python code as I've mentioned in a comment on JJ's answer.

Comment: I sometimes slash out sigils on variables whose values don't vary. There's a way to have variables without sigils that also vary but I'm not going to encourage you to go down that path because other folk will say nasty things about me. :)

Comment: raiph: ssssh! No one is supposed to know about that stuff haha

Answer (score 4):

As usual, the answer by @raiph is correct. I just want to do the minimal changes to your program that get it right. In this case, it's simply adding indices to both loops to make stuff clearer. You were using the context variable $_ in the first, and $^a in the second (inner), and it was getting unnecesarily confusing.

```
my @s=<1 1 2 2 1 3>;
my $k=2;
my $res=0;
for ^@s -> $i {
    my $seen = 0;
    my %window;
    for @s[$i..*] -> $c {
    if $c == %window.keys.none {
            $seen++;
            %window{$c} = 1;
    } else {  
            %window{$c} += 1;
    }
    if %window{$c} == $k {
            $seen--;
            if $seen == 0 {
        $res++;
        }
    } elsif %window{$c} > $k {
            last;
    }
    }
}
say $res;
```

As you see , besides trying to indent everything a bit more properly, the only additional thing is to add `-> $i` and `-> $c` so that loops are indexed, and then use them where you were using implicit variables.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I've forgotten the  `-> $i` type of assignment as I started writing the code.

Comment: "the only additional thing is to add `-> $i` and `-> $c`. I must protest. :) You switched the hash subscripts to array subscripts. "besides trying to indent everything a bit more properly" The `if $c == %window.keys.none {` line and subsequent ones are at the same indent as the `for @s[$i..*] -> $c {` line. By far the most baffling thing is the `for @s[$i..*] -> $c`. The original Python isn't looping over *values found in* the array it's looping over *indexes into* it. I stuck a `say $c` in to see what this code is doing. It goes thru a crazy sequence compared to the Python. Is the `4` luck?

Comment: @raiph it might very well be... and everything was indented properly... in emacs. It's mostly unsticking closing braces, anyway. But why do you say I switched hash subscripts to array subscripts? I just added those indices, and substituted them where they were...

Comment: No the `4` result is no luck because when tested with other inputs such as the `1102021222` string given in the question, it gives `6` and it's correct. Or some very basic string like `1122` should give `3`, the resulting *perfect substrings* being `11` `22` `1122`

Comment: @jjmerelo Maybe I'm going crazy. The Python original doesn't use a hash (dict) but rather an array. Obviously a hash/dict works but I think I was scrolling to the Python code or my code instead of yours when comparing. ‍♂️ But either I'm crazy or the following is weird. The inner `for` loop in the Python code is `for ind in range(i, len(s)):`. Aiui that iterates the integers from `i` to the length of `s`. I'm staring at what I think is Lars'/your Raku code, and it seems to iterate over *the values in the `@s` array*, from the value at the `i`th index to the last value in the array?!?  

Comment: Yes in my original code, it iterates over the values in the `@s`  `$^a` keeping the value instead of `s[ind]` in Python. The Python code never uses the index `ind` standalone.

Comment: @LarsMalmsteen Ah. Duh. Thx. :) Too little sleep! I made other mistakes. **1** "`for ind in range(i, len(s)):` Aiui that iterates ... to the length of `s`." **Wrong**. It iterates to *one less* than the length of `s`. **2** In a sort of similar vein, I thought `array[foo..*]` should be `array[foo..*-1]` and that `array[foo..*]` would yield an `Any` for the last value in its sequence. Despite 10 years writing Raku code, I managed to momentarily forget that `array[foo..*]` means `array[foo..Inf]` so ends up yielding the same result as `array[foo..*-1]`.  indeed. :)